# Cannot iterate over file list from dropped elements in browser web page with DataTransfer

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, dom-events, data-transfer

There are similar questions like this, but they don't explain why this fails.

After dropping multiple files into the browser, iterating with the `for...of` statement fails while the normal `for` loop works.

The `for...of` version outputs `undefined` for `file.name` while the normal `for` version outputs the filename correctly.

Why?

```
function initDragDropEvents() {
    // Trigger file uploads on drop events.
    $('body').on('drop', function(e) {
        let fileList = getFileListFromDropEvent(e.originalEvent);

        // Have image? Update view.
        for (const file in fileList) {
            console.log('1 Dropped file: ' + file.name);
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
            console.log('2 Dropped file: ' + fileList[i].name);
        }
    });
}

function getFileListFromDropEvent(event) {
   // Prevent default behavior, which opens the file.
   event.preventDefault();

   // Set default result for file.
   let fileList = [];

   // Get item list from @event.
   let itemList = event.dataTransfer.items;
   if (!itemList) {
    itemList = event.dataTransfer.files;
   }

   if (itemList) {
    for (const item of itemList) {
        // Assume DataTransfer interface by default.
            let file = item;

        // Use DataTransferItemList interface instead?
            if (item.kind === 'file') {
            file = item.getAsFile();
         }

         fileList.push(file);
    }
   }

   return fileList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by a subtle bug. Rather than delete the question, will post the answer in case someone else makes the same mistake in the future.

This works if you use `for...of` and not `for...in`.